# Flutter error decoding protobuf response from golang grpc server

Tags: go, flutter, dart, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've implemented a simple unary `gRPC` server in `golang` and I'm connecting to it from my phone over my local WAN with `flutter`.

The protobuf request is just an `int64` timestamp and the response is a single message `LoadResponse` that contains an **array of messages** of type `Load`.

The server is receiving the request perfectly and appears to be returning a response however flutter is having difficulty interpreting it and the error messages are not helpful:

I get 2 messages from flutter, one in **debug** and one **onscreen**:

## Debug:

`InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly
in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the
input has been truncated or that an embedded message
misreported its own length.`

## OnScreen

`gRPC Error(12, No responses received)`

Firstly, I don't know which error is accurate and neither make sense. The server is definitely receiving the request and returning a response. This implies that the service is recognised successfully so the `gRPC status code 12` error appears to be a false alarm.

Otherwise the debug message doesn't allude to what my problem could be. In my flutter code I used a `FutureBuilder<LoadResponse>` to load this response (as it is a unary call) but perhaps I need a `StreamBuilder` instead because it contains an array of messages?

## Code:

## lambda.proto

```proto
syntax= "proto3";
package client;
option go_package="lambdapb";

message Timestamp{
    int64 timestamp = 1;
}

message LoadRequest{
    Timestamp timestamp = 1;
}

service LoadService{
    rpc Load(LoadRequest) returns (LoadResponse){};
}

message Load {
    string deliverydate = 1;
    double splitnumber = 2;
    string temperature = 3;
    string firstname = 4;
    string loaddate = 5;
    double id = 6;
    double weight = 7;
    string ponumber = 8;
    string tsize = 9;
    string phone = 10;
    string equipment = 11;
    string ext = 12;
    double miles = 13;
    string lastname = 14;
  }

message LoadResponse{
    repeated Load loads = 1;
}
```

## main.go (server)

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "legion_server/lambdapb"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

var tlsConf = &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        Renegotiation: tls.RenegotiateOnceAsClient,
    },
}

var client = &http.Client{
    Timeout:   time.Duration(5 * time.Second),
    Transport: tlsConf,
}

func (*server) Load(ctx context.Context, req *lambdapb.LoadRequest) (*lambdapb.LoadResponse, error) {
    timestamp := req.GetTimestamp().GetTimestamp()
    fmt.Println(timestamp)
    unixTime, err := time.Unix(timestamp, 0).MarshalText()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error converting timestamp to RFC 3339: %v", err)
    }
    data := pullNewLoads(string(unixTime))
    response := &lambdapb.LoadResponse{
        Loads: data,
    }
    fmt.Println(response)
    return response, nil
}

type server struct{}

func main() {

    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:50051")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to listen %v", err)
    }

    serv := grpc.NewServer()
    lambdapb.RegisterLoadServiceServer(serv, &server{})
    if err := serv.Serve(listen); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to server: %v", err)
    }

}

func pullNewLoads(timestamp string) []*lambdapb.Load {

    formData := url.Values{
        "top":   {"10"},
        "lDate": {timestamp},
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.*********.com/AppAvailLoads?", strings.NewReader(formData.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating request")
    }

    req.Header.Add("x-cdata-authtoken", "************")
    req.Header.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in request")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close() // defer only calls body.close() when pullNewLoads() returns

    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var data map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error decoding json")
    }
    values, err := json.Marshal(data["value"].([]interface{}))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var results []*lambdapb.Load

    if err := json.Unmarshal(values, &results); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error unmarshalling into struct %v", err)
    }

    return results
}
```

## Flutter:

## load_service.dart

```dart
import 'package:Lambda/proto/lambdapb/lambda.pbgrpc.dart';
import 'package:fixnum/fixnum.dart';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';

class LoadService {
  static LoadServiceClient client;

  LoadService(){
    client = LoadServiceClient(ClientChannel(
      "192.168.1.87",
      port: 50051,
      options: ChannelOptions(credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure())
    ));
  }
  Timestamp generateTimestamp(){
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp();
    timestamp.setField(1, Int64((DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 365)).millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).round()));
    return timestamp;
  }

  Future<LoadResponse> getNewLoads(){
    print('Starting request');
    LoadRequest request = LoadRequest();
    request.setField(1, generateTimestamp());
    print('field set, waiting');
    return client.load(request);
  }
}
```

## Screen:

```dart
class RoleSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  LoadService api;
  RoleSelect({Key key}){
    api = new LoadService();
  }

  _RoleSelectState createState() => _RoleSelectState();
}
// more code
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
                  child: FutureBuilder<LoadResponse>(
            future: this.widget.api.getNewLoads(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                print(snapshot.data.getField(1));
                return Text("Response received");
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
              } else {
                return Text(snapshot.connectionState.toString());
              }
            },
          ),
        )
}
```

## Edit 1:

The service works fine when I return a `string` instead of `repeated Load loads`, it appears as though the dart code is having an error unpacking the array?